# Training Tesseract on specific fonts results in empty tr files

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm working on a college project that involves OCRing a certain digit-code (with a few other characters as seperators - mainly '.','/' etc..) . 
that digit code (printed on products for example) is usually in "digital" fonts (e.g. 7-segment-like font, or a pixelated font etc.).

So I am trying to train Tesseract on several digital fonts I've found online, similar to those used with these code.

The thing is, that Tesseract recognizes the tiff files I provide it as blank pages.

Things I've tried: 
1. creating a .box file using JTesseract & qt-box (and adjusting the boxes manually) : in this case, the box & tiff are read by Tesseract and I'm getting the output "1 Page", but no characters are recognized and the tr file in blank.

2. creating a .box file with Tesseract's makebox - in this case no boxes are created at all.

PS - I manage to train it just fine using more traditional fonts (Arial for example)
Any ideas? 
Im attaching an image of such an example font. 
[image: digitized font]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to work around most of the issues. Posting it in case it could help anyone else:
I did 2 steps to get Tesseract to identify my text:

1. Image processing on the training images - I've applied some image processing methods (mainly dilate, erode and some blur) to sort of "connect" the pixels in the text that were segmented or separated from one another. Its VERY IMPORTANT to apply the same steps exactly to the images to be fed to the OCR.
2. I've noticed that simply saving images as TIFF/PNGs via code doesn't save the DPI setting in the header for some reason (and Tesseract identified the as 0 DPI). I assume there's a code-way to do that but I didn't have time, so I just opened the files in Photoshop and saved them from there.

I'm not entirely sure if it was step 1,2 or both that solved my issue, but most characters were eventually identified.